# How can I toggle between 2 classes on click on the same element on JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Need your help on something,

Trying to toggle between classes when I click on an element on an HTML page but unfortunately once toggled I cannot change it back.

Even tried returning the querySelector but no luck.

Here is the code I wrote;

```js
let fetchNumbers = document.querySelectorAll(`.cardnumber`);

for (let index = 0; index < fetchNumbers.length; index++) {

  if (fetchNumbers[index].classList.contains('unselected') === true) {
    fetchNumbers[index].addEventListener(`click`, function() {
      fetchNumbers[index].classList.add(`selected`);
      fetchNumbers[index].classList.remove(`unselected`);
      fetchNumbers = document.querySelectorAll(`.cardnumber`);
      return fetchNumbers;
    });
  } else {
    fetchNumbers[index].addEventListener(`click`, function() {
      fetchNumbers[index].classList.add(`unselected`);
      fetchNumbers[index].classList.remove(`selected`);
      fetchNumbers = document.querySelectorAll(`.cardnumber`)
      return fetchNumbers;
    });
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have You tried using the `toggle()` method? I think that it might be what You're looking for

Give it a shot!

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_class

Another example that might be helpful

https://codepen.io/StrengthandFreedom/pen/ZOGVLg

Comment: Thank you so much i am self teaching and this is perfect, thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

I've created an Asp.NET Core application to test/debug your code with a fresh html page and javascript with your code snippet.

If this code block below is the only code in your Javascript file,

```
let fetchNumbers = document.querySelectorAll(`.cardnumber`);

for (let index = 0; index < fetchNumbers.length; index++) {

if (fetchNumbers[index].classList.contains('unselected') === true) {
    fetchNumbers[index].addEventListener(`click`, function () {
        fetchNumbers[index].classList.add(`selected`);
        fetchNumbers[index].classList.remove(`unselected`);
        fetchNumbers = document.querySelectorAll(`.cardnumber`);
        return fetchNumbers;
    }); 
} else {
    fetchNumbers[index].addEventListener(`click`, function () {
        fetchNumbers[index].classList.add(`unselected`);
        fetchNumbers[index].classList.remove(`selected`);
        fetchNumbers = document.querySelectorAll(`.cardnumber`)
        return fetchNumbers;
    }); 
}
```

**Info**

Javascript files are loaded statically, which means they are ran immediately after the html page is loaded into the DOM, so this code is run immediately after the html page is loaded.

**Problem**

Based upon the classes defined by your html elements (in this case - `class="cardnumber unselected"`), once the page loads, your code block above would hit the first `if` statement, then assign the `click event` to all `cardnumber` elements, then proceed to change the class from `unselected` to `selected`.
When you go to click your html element the second time, the click event from the `if` block in your `if/else` block will **NOT** be ran as the page has already loaded. This means the `else` block will never execute.
This is the reason you are not seeing any functionality on the second click.

*****note*****

Javascript events can only be defined once, so you'd never be able to bind both the `click events` in the `if` block AND `else` block.

***Solution***

Define *the* `click event` for your `cardnumber`. Move your if/else logic into your new `click event` like below:

```
let fetchNumbers = document.querySelectorAll('.cardNumber');

for (let index = 0; index < fetchNumbers.length; index++) {

    fetchNumbers[index].addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (fetchNumbers[index].classList.contains('unselected') === true) {
            fetchNumbers[index].classList.add('selected');
            fetchNumbers[index].classList.remove('unselected');
            fetchNumbers = document.querySelectorAll('.cardNumber');
            return fetchNumbers;
        } else {
            fetchNumbers[index].classList.add('unselected');
            fetchNumbers[index].classList.remove('selected');
            fetchNumbers = document.querySelectorAll('.cardNumber')
            return fetchNumbers;
        }
    });
}
```